# Java overloading and overriding

Tags: java, overriding, overloading

We always say that method overloading is static polymorphism and overriding is runtime polymorphism. What exactly do we mean by static here? Is the call to a method resolved on compiling the code? So whats the difference between normal method call and calling a final method? Which one is linked at compile time?

Answer (score 23):

Method overloading means making multiple versions of a function based on the inputs. For example:

```
public Double doSomething(Double x) { ... }
public Object doSomething(Object y) { ... }
```

The choice of which method to call is made at compile time. For example:

```
Double obj1 = new Double();
doSomething(obj1); // calls the Double version

Object obj2 = new Object();
doSomething(obj2); // calls the Object version

Object obj3 = new Double();
doSomething(obj3); // calls the Object version because the compilers see the 
                   // type as Object
                   // This makes more sense when you consider something like

public void myMethod(Object o) {
  doSomething(o);
}
myMethod(new Double(5));
// inside the call to myMethod, it sees only that it has an Object
// it can't tell that it's a Double at compile time
```

Method Overriding means defining a new version of the method by a subclass of the original

```
class Parent {
  public void myMethod() { ... }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  @Override
  public void myMethod() { ... }
}

Parent p = new Parent();
p.myMethod(); // calls Parent's myMethod

Child c = new Child();
c.myMethod(); // calls Child's myMethod

Parent pc = new Child();
pc.myMethod(); // call's Child's myMethod because the type is checked at runtime
               // rather than compile time
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 11):

Your are right - calls to overloaded methods are realized at compile time. That's why it is *static*.

Calls to overridden methods are realized at run-time, based on the type on which the method is invoked.

[On virtual methods wikipedia says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Java)

> In Java, all non-static methods are by default "virtual functions." Only methods marked with the keyword final are non-virtual.

`final` methods cannot be overridden, so they are realized statically.

Imagine the method:

```
public String analyze(Interface i) {
     i.analyze();
     return i.getAnalysisDetails();
}
```

The compiler can't overload this method for all implementations of `Interface` that can possibly be passed to it.

Comment: Are final methods really handled differently at run-time? Or is the final-ness only enforced at compile-time?

Comment: Another interesting aspect is that only part of the method dispatch for overridden methods takes place at runtime: At compile-time, the exact method signature is established, regardless of the runtime types of parameter values. The only dispatch that happens at runtime is on the type of the object whose method is being invoked.

Comment: @Thilo I'm not entirely sure how final methods are handled at runtime. It should be written in the spec (which I'm a bit lazy to search now)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can call overloading any sort of polymorphism. Overloaded methods are linked at compile time, which kind of precludes calling it polymorphism.

Polymorphism refers to the dynamic binding of a method to its call when you use a base class reference for a derived class object. Overriding methods is how you implement this polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: No – “polymorphism” is *any* mechanism by which different behaviour is implemented depending on types. Whether the dispatching happens at runtime or compile time is completely irrelevant for the definition of polymorphism. FYI, in contexts where a further classification is needed, overloading is usually called “ad-hoc polymorphism”.

Comment: We call method overloading static polymorphism (compile time polymorphism) and method overriding dynamic polymorphism (runtime polymorphism).

Answer (score 1):

i agree with rachel, because in K&B book it is directly mentioned that **overloading does not belong to polymorphism** in chapter 2(object orientation). But in lots of places i found that overloading means static polymorphism because it is compile time and overriding means dynamic polymorphism because it s run time.

But one interesting thing is in a C++ book (Object-Oriented Programming in C++ - Robert Lafore) it is also directly mentioned that overloading means static polymorphism.
But one more thing is there java and c++ both are two different programing languages and they have different object manipulation techniques so may be polymorphism differs in c++ and java ?

Answer (score 1):

**Method Overloading** simply means providing two separate methods in a class with the same name but different arguments while method return type may or may not be different which allows us to reuse the same method name.

But both methods are different hence can be resolved by compiler at compile time that's is why it is also known as **Compile Time Polymorphism** or **Static Polymorphism**

**Method Overriding** means defining a method in the child class which is already defined in the parent class with same method signature i.e same name, arguments and return type.

```
Mammal mammal = new Cat();
System.out.println(mammal.speak());
```

At the line `mammal.speak()` compiler says the `speak()` method of reference type `Mammal` is getting called, so for compiler this call is `Mammal.speak()`.

But at the execution time JVM knows clearly that `mammal` reference is holding the reference of object of `Cat`, so for JVM this call is `Cat.speak()`.

Because method call is getting resolved at runtime by JVM that's why it is also known as **Runtime Polymorphism** and **Dynamic Method Dispatch**.

**Difference Between Method Overloading and Method Overriding**

[image: Difference Between Method Overloading and Method Overriding]

For more details, you can read [Everything About Method Overloading Vs Method Overriding](https://programmingmitra.blogspot.in/2017/05/everything-about-method-overloading-vs-method-overriding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple Definition - Method overloading deals with the notion of having two or more methods(functions) in the same class with the same name but different arguments.

While Method overriding means having two methods with the same arguments, but different implementation. One of them would exist in the Parent class (Base Class) while another will be in the derived class(Child Class).@Override annotation is required for this.

Check this : 
[Click here for a detailed example](http://yhisham.blogspot.in/2012/09/java-what-is-difference-between-method.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Property**                  Over-loading                Overriding

Method Names -------------->must be Same----------------must be same

Arg Types------------------>must be Different(at least arg)

Method Signature

Return Type

Private,Static,Final

Access Modifier

try/Catch

Method Resolution

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to discuss Run-time/Dynamic polymorphism and Compile-time/static polymorphism.

### Compile-time/static polymorphism:- as its name suggests that it bind the function call to its appropriate Function at compile time. That means the compiler exactly know which function call associated to which function. Function overloading is an example of compile time polymorphism.

### Run-time/Dynamic polymorphism:-In this type of polymorphism compiler don't know which functions call associates to which function until the run of the program. Eg. function overriding.

NOW, what are the function overriding and function overloading???

Function Overloading:- same function name but different function signature/parameter.

```
eg. Area(no. of parameter) 
        {     -------------
           ----------------
             return area;}

         area of square requires  only one parameter
         area of rectangle requires two parameters(Length and breadth)
```

function overriding:- alter the work of a function which is present in both the Superclass and Child class.
                eg.  name() in superclass prints "hello Rahul" but after overring in child class it prints "hello Akshit"

Answer (score 0):

Tried to cover all differences

```
                       Overloading                          Overriding

Method Name            Must be same                         Must be same

Argument Types         Must be same                         Must be different


Return Type            No restriction                       Must be same till 1.4V 
                                                            but after 1.4V 
                                                            co- variants 
                                                            were introduced

private/static/final   Can be overloaded                    Cannot be overridden

Access Modifiers       No restriction                       Cannot reduce the scope

Throws keyword         No restriction                       If child class method 
                                                            throws a checked 
                                                            exception the parent 
                                                            class method must throw 
                                                            the same or the  
                                                            parent exception

Method Resolution      Taken care by compiler               Taken care by JVM based 
                       based on reference types             on run-time object

Known as               Compile-Time Polymorphism,           RunTime Polymorphism, 
                       Static Polymorphism, or              dynamic polymorphism,
                       early binding                        late binding.
```