# Is this program overloading or overriding?

Tags: overriding, overloading

Today one company interviewer asked me what is this program, is it **overloading** or is it **overriding?**

```
int a(int n1, int n2)
float a(int n1, int n2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is method overloading and overriding needed in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228520/why-is-method-overloading-and-overriding-needed-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymorphism vs Overriding vs Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it is overloading because some of the modern language support this methodology**

> overloading by return type is possible and is done by some modern
>   languages. The usual objection is that in code like

```
int func();
string func();
int main() { func(); }
```

Comment: I searched some forum and i found that it is not possible in c#? Is it true? I said its overloading I think  i given the wrong answer.

Comment: yes in c# programming language does not support this feature but many modern programming language support that feature

Comment: So literally my answer was wrong in .net interview.