display method not compiling in Main JAVA
I can't figure out how to call the display method from shape class to the Main method. This is for an assignment, and we're not supposed to change what's written in Main, so the problem has to come from the shape class. All the comments are straight from the instructions. This is done in Java.
Edit
The error is specifically in the Main method for obj.display() and obj1.display(). The error reads "Cannot resolve method 'display()'". It recommended "void display(String)" and "String display(String, String)" but when I tried those, neither of them worked.
class Shape {
    // declare String variable for result and double to store area
    String result;
    double area;

    public String display(String res, String result) {
        // display method should add res parameter to result and return the result
        return result += res;
    }

    public double area() {
        //area method should initialize area to 0
        return area = 0;
    }

    static double area(double area) {
        return area = 0;
    }
}

    //create a child class triangle for shape
    class Triangle extends Shape {
        //declare variable length and width
        double length;
        double width;

        public Triangle(double length, double width) {
            //initialize length and width inside constructor and then call area method
            this.length = length;
            this.width = width;

            area();
        }
            // override area method to calculate area of triangle
            public double area() {
                return length * width / 2;
            }

            //override display method which returns the output of parent class display method
            public void display(String res){
                super.display(res, result);
            }

            //implement toString method to return the class name
            public String toString(){
                return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            }
    }


    //create a child class circle for shape
    class Circle extends Shape{
        //declare a constant and initialize pi value
        double c = Math.PI;
        //declare variable radius
        double radius;

        public Circle(double radius) {
            //initialize radius inside constructor
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        //and then call area method
        public double area(){
            // override area method to calculate area of circle
            return c*Math.pow(radius, 2);
        }

        //override display method which returns the output of parent class display method
        void display(String res){
            super.display(res, result);
        }

        //implement toString method to return the class name
        public String toString(){
            return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle obj= new Triangle(10,20);
        System.out.println("The area of "+obj+" With dimensions "+obj.length +" and "+obj.width+" is: " + obj.display());

        Circle obj1= new Circle(10);
        System.out.println("The area of "+obj1+" With radius "+obj1.radius +" is: "+obj1.display());
    }
}

I tried to follow the error messages and automated suggestions I was given, but they didn't make a difference. I changed it from void to public String and tried moving the method around in the different classes, but to no avail.

How can we know what's wrong here and what is the expected behaviour? ;)

That's the issue, I'm not entirely sure of the error. I just know it has something to do with the display method not carrying over to the Main class. display() is supposed to print the area of the Triangle/Circle (depending on if it's called from class Triangle or class Circle)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Small tip: whenever you're overriding a method, add @Override annotation, it's easier to spot whether you're actually overriding a method or not. In general, I suggest reading about overriding vs overloading, fe. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469767/java-overloading-and-overriding

I figured it out! I had to change the display method contents to this vvv
            public String display(){
            return Double.toString(area());
        }

